How to wrap functions for visibility in R?
Knitting an R Markdown file to pdf results in lines that are cut off. In order to wrap them, I added the following code that wraps output text. However, I also want to wrap code and functions so they're visible in pdf format.
library(knitr)
hook_output = knit_hooks$get('output')
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  # this hook is used only when the linewidth option is not NULL
  if (!is.null(n <- options$linewidth)) {
    x = xfun::split_lines(x)
    # any lines wider than n should be wrapped
    if (any(nchar(x) > n)) x = strwrap(x, width = n)
    x = paste(x, collapse = '\n')
  }
  hook_output(x, options)
})

This wraps function outputs, but the function still runs of the page. Pressing enter to have it be on multiple lines leads to \n being printed. Is there a way to get rid of this \n while still allowing function code to be fully seen in pdf format? In the example below, I pressed enter for the sprintf function to get it all on the page. But there's now an undesirable \n in the output.


How are code blocks rendered in the LaTeX output produced by pandoc? If it’s using (or can be configured to use) ‘minted’, you can instruct LaTeX to wrap those blocks using the breaklines option. The result is arguably prettier than hard-wrapping lines.

The output hook will only process the output from a chunk. To wrap the source code you have to add a source hook:
---
output: pdf_document
date: "2024-05-01"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(knitr)

wrap_helper <- function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(n <- options$linewidth)) {
    x <- xfun::split_lines(x)
    if (any(nchar(x) > n)) x <- strwrap(x, width = n)
    x <- paste(x, collapse = "\n")
  }
  x
}

hook_output <- knit_hooks$get("output")
hook_source <- knit_hooks$get("source")

knit_hooks$set(
  output = function(x, options) {
    hook_output(wrap_helper(x, options), options)
  },
  source = function(x, options) {
    hook_source(wrap_helper(x, options), options)
  }
)
```

```{r linewidth=40}
sprintf("nunc aptent eu viverra habitant imperdiet ante ultricies tristique convallis nunc aptent eu viverra habitant imperdiet ante ultricies tristique convallis")
```


